# next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

NextJS project shows the following logs in the terminal. Do you have any idea about the reason of this?

```
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 10.8s (2827 modules)
next-translate - compiled page: /app/[privateKey]/[...sections] - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /app/[privateKey] - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
next-translate - compiled page: /_error - locale: en - namespaces: common - used loader: getInitialProps
```